# how to make @JoinTable immutable

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

how to make @JoinTable immutable???

Here in the case, I am looking to make latest_history immutable

```
class Record {

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
  @JoinTable(name = "latest_history", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "record_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "history_id") })
  @AccessType("field")
  public History getLatestHistory() { ... }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "immutable"? is annotating with `@Immutable` what you want?

Comment: I waanted to make the table non editable but the set has to be editable, hope I am clear @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "joinedTable", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "column_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "other_id"))
    @ForeignKey(name = "entities_fk", inverseName = "messages_fk")
    @OrderBy(value = "displaySequence")
    public Set<MemberMessage> getMessages() {
 return messages;
    }

Answer (score 1):

In XML mapping file set mutable to false for eg:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mkyong.common.Stock" table="stock" mutable="false" >
```

And then put @Immutable annotation above your mapping code

hope it will help

Comment: Sorry I have put wrong example first, I have many-to-many relation but not one-to-one, and I wanted to make just the table immutable but not the set,                                                                   @ManyToMany @JoinTable(name = "joinedTable", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "column_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "other_id")) @ForeignKey(name = "entities_fk", inverseName = "messages_fk") @OrderBy(value = "displaySequence") public Set<MemberMessage> getMessages() { return messages; }

Comment: use @immutable in class where you have declared the variable of that particular table which you want to make immutabel.